# Hidden labels in ggplot stacked facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to increase ylim of the facets by a certain percentage so my labels fit in nicely?
At the moment the very small bars will have a half cut off label above them. When I use hjust I have the same problem on the top of the large bars.

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=YEAR, y=(value), fill=variable)) +
   labs(title="Test", x=NULL, y="Total", fill=NULL) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity"), position="stack") + 
   facet_grid(variable ~., scales="free") +
   theme(legend.position = "none") + 
   geom_text(aes(x=YEAR, y=(value), label=value), size=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expand` in `scale_y_continuous` to add some space at the top and bottom:

e.g.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=YEAR, y=(value), fill=variable)) +
   labs(title="Test", x=NULL, y="Total", fill=NULL) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity"), position="stack") + 
   facet_grid(variable ~., scales="free") +
   theme(legend.position = "none") + 
   geom_text(aes(x=YEAR, y=(value), label=value), size=3)+
   scale_y_continuous( expand = c( 0.05 , 0.05 ) )
```

This will add a small amount of space at the top and bottom of the y-scale. Make it bigger for more space and 0 to trim axes exactly at the range of the data.

For dscrete scales it works in much the same way:

```
scale_y_discrete( expand = c( 0.05 , 0.05 ) )
```

An extreme example (since I don't have access to your data):

```
mm <- ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarise, mmpg = mean(mpg))
ggplot(mm, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mmpg , fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text( aes( label=c("RED","GREEN","BLUE" ) ), size = 15 )+
  scale_y_continuous( expand = c(0.5,0.5) )
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks you soooo much. Now I only have to figure out why every second tick mark isn't labelled on the x axis.

Comment: @JoanneDemmler no problem. The answer to that also lies in the scales argument (check breaks and labels arguments)